# How to search string between two character in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to search string between two characters in JavaScript, jQuery.

Here id my url

> http://local.evibe-dash.in/vendors/new?status=Phone&count=60&type="artist,magic".

I want to search string between `"status=" and first &`, so that when I will get other value than this, then I can put in URL.

Comment: are you trying to do get parameters?

Comment: ya,actually I want to put the value of status if it changes after selecting from drop-down list

Comment: `var str='http://local.evibe-dash.in/vendors/new?status=Phone&count=60&type="artist,magic".'; str.substring(str.indexOf('status=')+7,str.indexOf('&'))`

Comment: my "status" position is not fixed in th url, it can be come after type, it depends on which filter is selected first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** with capturing group regex

```js
var str = 'http://local.evibe-dash.in/vendors/new?status=Phone&count=60&type="artist,m‌​agic".';

var res = str.match(/status=([^&]+)/)[1]

document.write(res);
```

---

or using **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)**

```js
var str = 'http://local.evibe-dash.in/vendors/new?status=Phone&count=60&type="artist,m‌​agic".';

var res = str.split('status=')[1].split('&')[0];

document.write(res);
```

---

or using **[`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)** and **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)**

```js
var str = 'http://local.evibe-dash.in/vendors/new?status=Phone&count=60&type="artist,m‌​agic".',
  ind = str.indexOf('status=');

var res = str.substring(ind + 7, str.indexOf('&', ind));

document.write(res);
```

Comment: thanks man. you solved my problem of dynamic refreshing the url.